# How to parse an URL String to URI or Bitmap and use it for CropImageView in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, uri, crop

I'm trying to create an image crop functionality using CropImageView from ArthurHub's Library and I have a string URL like **https://mywebsite.com/library/folder/KeYO8Ff31l178kO.png**. Is possible to parse this link to URI or Bitmap so I can use setImageUriAsync or setImageBitmap to set the image? I'm using Kotlin. Thanks

***LATER EDIT***:
**I found the solution, I'm not sure if it's the best but maybe will be useful:**
I created this inner class and inside it I parsed the url to bitmap and in OnPostExecute method I set the resource for cropImageView.

**Code:**

```
internal class GetBitmapFromUrlAsync(private val cropImageView: CropImageView) : AsyncTask<String, Void?, Bitmap>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg src: String): Bitmap? {
        val url = URL(src[0])
        val bitmap: Bitmap
         try {
            val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection
            connection.doInput = true
            connection.connect()
            val input: InputStream = connection.inputStream
             bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
             return null
        }
        return bitmap
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(bitmap: Bitmap?) {
        cropImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using libraries like [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/)  or [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) ?

Comment: @VarshaKulkarni no, I thought I can't use those libraries with CropImageView, only with ImageView, am I right?